# How to group Location coordinates based on Zipcode?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I'm new to Zipcode, Location Coordinates subject. I am working on a Mobile App where we are going to implement Openweather JSON.

Each Zipcode has a fixed coordinate point mentioned in the JSON.

As per my understanding, coordinates will vary on every move.

How can i group the coordinates based on Zipcode?